# Media queries not working on iPhone Safari browser

Tags: css, iphone, responsive-design

I've built a site using media queries to make it responsive and whilst I've been developing it I have changed the width of the browser to test [the page](http://replyonline.co.uk/DirectionGroup/18955_DG_Retail_website_update/05_Technical/landing_page/) and the media queries seem to work fine with the break points I have set.

Problem is though, when testing the actual page on the iPhone, it doesn't seem to be recognizing the media queries at all and the full desktop view is shown in the browser instead.

Why ideas why an iPhone would do this, any mobile phone for that matter?

Here's the Litmus browser test result I have: https://litmus.com/pub/b78644d

Comment: Please paste the relevant parts of your code in your question instead of linking to external resources. Live pages are likely to change from their current form, severely damaging the helpfulness of this question to future users encountering similar problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could take it a step further with

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

I'd also recommend wiping out some of those !important(s), at least off of the widths you've set, so the responsiveness plays nicely.

Annnnnd Chrome has a sweet (relatively new) emulation tool built in that you can mess around with and use it to view your site scaled down to mobile as well - it's tucked in next to the Javascript Console.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem adding this line to the head in the HTML:-

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```